# Is it possible to share a Master Page between projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

We have several different MVC2 projects on the go and I would like to be able to share a single master page between them.

Is there an easy way to do this without recreating the same master page in each project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the master page as a link if the projects sharing the master page are in the same solution.  Add->Existing item->browse to the master page file and select "Add as Link".

Comment: Actually, this worked when I just added the file (not added as a link) though obviously in that case a copy of the file was created. However, when I then went back and added the file as a link, the Master Page file was not found.

Comment: You may need to update the pages that inherit from it to have a relative url rather than the ~/ notation that it points to it by default.