# Is there a way to implement a single master page across multiple existing web applications?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, iis-10

Developing setup: VS 2013 on Windows 10 Pro 
Host server for production: IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016

My goal is to have a master page that I can reference for the majority of our web applications so we can achieve some uniformity among webpages on our intranet. For now, my plan was only to have the company logo and some links.

The physical structure on our server is something like: 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainApp 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainApp\App1
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainApp\App2
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainApp\AppN

and in IIS:
HostServer
-> Sites
->->Default Web Site
->->->MainApp
->->->->App1
->->->->App2
->->->->MasterPage

I added the MasterPage directory with a containing .master file in hopes that I could reference it from App1,App2, etc. The master file is as follows:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="topContent">
              <img src="companylogo.jpg" alt="" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="mainContent">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a new web app called NewTestWithMasterPage and added a web form called WebForm1.aspx. The following is my current code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/../MasterPage/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="NewTestWithMasterPage.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

I published NewTestWithMasterPage and copied the published files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewTestWithMasterPage on the host server.

In IIS Manager I navigated to HostServer->Sites->Default Web Site->MainApp and found my NewTestWithMasterPage folder. I right clicked and converted that folder to an application. I also added a virtual directory with Alias "MasterPage" and physical path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MasterPage.

When I launch the page I expect to see a logo with a list of links. Instead I receive the following error:

> The virtual path '/MainApp/MasterPage/Site.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412745/is-there-any-way-to-load-a-master-page-from-outside-the-current-application) stackoverflow question as a reference since I believe I am having the same error. The fix of adding a virtual directory to my MasterPage in my NewTestWithMasterPage folder did not seem to work for me though.

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399975/is-it-possible-to-share-a-master-page-between-projects

Comment: My web applications have separate solutions. @LexLi

Comment: If you use a proper source code control system, then sharing the same file across multiple solutions is nothing difficult.

Comment: We do not have a source code control system. It is something I have been curious about and would like to look into further though.

Comment: Wow this technology is still alive?

Comment: When you create an empty asp.net webform or mvc application, it will generate a project with master page. And if you deploy it on IIS, it will auto use master page.